# What is this name of form of ODE?$~ A \frac{ dy }{ dx } + B y=C~ $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After read of [this cheat sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi6tcGcvorzAhXN7GEKHUnSBzMQFnoECAMQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.uncw.edu%2Fhermanr%2Fmat361%2FODEsheet.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Rgy8ntN9dyVNIx0RLLDzI), I couldn't find the name of the form of the below ODE .

$$  A \frac{  dy  }{ dx   } + B y=C   $$

$$  A,B,C:=\text{constants}  $$

I want to find out a general solution of $~ q ~$ of the below equation .

$$  \underbrace{R}_{A}  \frac{  dq  }{ dt   } + \underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{ C_{1} } +\frac{1}{C_{2}}  \right)}_{B}  q= \underbrace{V_{1}-V_{2}}_{C}   $$

$$  q |_{ t=0 } =0 $$

As I knew the name of the form , I think I can find out a general solution in my own .

I think assuming $~C~$ as a constant function of $~x~$ is one of the knack(s) .

Comment: First order non-homogenous linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the ODE is separable, or you can use an integrating factor. For $A\neq 0$  we have

$$A \frac{  dy  }{ dx   } + B y=C$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{B}{A}y=\frac{C}{A}$$

and multiplying by the integrating factor $e^{\int \frac{B}{A} dx}=e^{\frac{B}{A}x+c}=e^{\frac{B}{A}x}e^{c}$ we have

$$e^{c}\left[e^{\frac{B}{A}x}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{B}{A}e^{\frac{B}{A}x}y\right]=e^{c}\frac{C}{A}e^{\frac{B}{A}x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(ye^{\frac{B}{A}x}\right)=\frac{C}{A}e^{\frac{B}{A}x}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I reached to the last line but my hand stopped from it .
BTW I think $$~\exp\left(\int\frac{B}{A}dx\right)=\exp\left(\frac{B}{A}x+\text{const}\right)~$$ should be held , why the constant of integration can be assumed zero always ?

Comment: I've edited above, you can take it to be zero since it cancels on both sides. The key is to find $P(x)$ such that $y'+a(x)y$ can be written as $\frac{d}{dx}\left(Py\right)$.  See [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) and [2](https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-ode.pdf).

Comment: Got the general solution .

Comment: $$  y= \frac{  C  }{ B   }+ \text{const} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{  Bx  }{ A   } \right)   $$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can substitute into the ODE and check that it is indeed the general solution.

Comment: Yay . Understood it .